# I have deleted my .android keystore but I didn't use it, how do I generate a new one?

Tags: flutter, android-keystore

I used keystore for the first time in a random app I made to as my first ever flutter app but now I am making an actual app and I would like to sign it with the keystone. I could not remember the password and so I just deleted the file hoping I could make a new one but now I cannot find instructions on how to generate an android flutter keystore.

Does anyone know how I could make one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload`

You can find your keystore in C directory. Or change the location as your wish.

Refer [Here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore)

Comment: If the answer usefull then accpet the answer, This helps others.

Comment: I just tried this but I got an error keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <androiddebugkey> does not exist

Comment: You have to edit this command based on you need and situation. Such as change `%userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks` to your location i.e `c:\upload-keystore.jks`. I have updated the answer.